openpyxl list of datatype list into single row multiple columns
I apologize if my formatting is not good i do not use stack overflow often.
My issue is I have a list which I want to append data to in an excel sheet where each time the script is run I want it to add data to the next row and populate the column cells in that row, so adding data horizontally in the table, however, when using the section of code below it adds each index as a new row and it is stacking the data vertically. I tried nesting for loops but as I am a beginner, probably due to poor implementation on my part, it made things messy.
The structure of the list would look something like this each time the script is run:
stats = [[25.564994], [36.41515], [14.5465], [15.1859541], ['example'], ['example']]

How I'd like the data formatted using the above structure of the list stats[]:

and once running the script again and getting another round of data id like it to log that data in the next row.
file_path = 'filename'
wb = load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb.active
for data in stats:
    sheet.append(data)
wb.save(filename='filename')

i tired using nested for loops like i said earlier but i seemed to make a mess of things so i went back to the original structure as in the code block, however, I'm a bit stuck now and not sure what to try.

Your original code is in the right direction. 
If you just flattened the list from a list of lists to a single list of values it would work.
'stats' list is changed to;
[25.564994, 36.41515, 14.5465, 15.1859541, 'example', 'example'] 
and then append to the Sheet as you are doing
from openpyxl import load_workbook


stats = [[25.564994], [36.41515], [14.5465], [15.1859541], ['example'], ['example']]

file_path = 'filename.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb.active

# flatten the list of lists to a single list
data = [ele for group in stats for ele in group]

sheet.append(data)
wb.save(filename='filename.xlsx')


import openpyxl
import os

stats = [[25.564994], [36.41515], [14.5465], [15.1859541], ['example'], ['example']]


filename = 'whatever_name_it_is.xlsx'

if not os.path.exists(filename):   #this line is checking weather the file name already exist or not if not then it will create a new file of the previously specified name
    book = openpyxl.Workbook()
    book.save(filename)
else:
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename) #like i said if the file name already exist it will open that file

#now it will look for the sheet name in the file ( in this case "sheet_1") if sheet_1 exist it will  use it, otherwise it will create a new one
sheet1 = book.get_sheet_by_name("sheet_1") if "sheet_1" in book.sheetnames else book.create_sheet("sheet_1") 

# in the following line it will the stats value in the sheet from row 3 and column 2 onwards, starting with B3
for i in range(len(stats)):
    sheet1.cell(row=3, column=i+2, value=stats[i][0]) #after each iteration it will  go to the next row with the i value incrementing each time

#finally it will save the file
book.save(filename)

# and a confirmation message just to confirm
print("Operation Successful \n Check the excel file in the current working directory")

I have utilized a for loop to iterate over the length of the list. With each iteration, the column number value of the sheet increases to save the next element in the subsequent column, progressing horizontally. The initial 'if' statements verify whether the file name already exists or not. I have provided explanations within the comments for clarity.

this is absolutely going in the right direction, it posts the data in a row just how i want it, it is overwriting the data with each successive run though. maybe for the row i can run something to check next empty row and use that for row=(next empty row)
